# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to learn Laravel, and I'm following a series of tutorials called laracast. I'm at [episode 24](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/24), "Forms that submit PUT requests. The short story is that the markup uses a hidden value to set the method to PUT, although the forms method is set to POST. Still, when I do this, I get the error message from the title:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException 
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

From the tutorials, I'd expect POST to also be a supported method. However, when I try to fix this, all resources I can find simply tells me what I already know. PUT is not supported, but I can fake it/override it, and then they refer to what I have already done... Are there any other reasons why I might get this error message?

HTML Form:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/competition-categories">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="competition-category-name-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="competition-category-name-input" name="competition-category-name-input" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ $competitionCategory->name }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="competition-category-abbreviation-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Abbreviation</label>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input id="competition-category-abbreviation-input" name="competition-category-abbreviation-input" type="text" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ $competitionCategory->abbreviation }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

web.php snippet:

```
//Competition Categories
Route::get('/competition-categories', 'CompetitionCategoryController@index');
Route::get('/competition-categories/create', 'CompetitionCategoryController@create');
Route::get('/competition-categories/{competitionCategory}', 'CompetitionCategoryController@show');
Route::get('/competition-categories/{competitionCategory}/edit', 'CompetitionCategoryController@edit');
Route::post('/competition-categories/{competitionCategory}', 'CompetitionCategoryController@store');
Route::put('/competition-categories/{competitionCategory}', 'CompetitionCategoryController@udpate');
Route::delete('/competition-categories/{competitionCategory}', 'CompetitionCategoryController@destroy');
```

Snippet from the controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, CompetitionCategory $competitionCategory)
{
    $competitionCategory->update($this->validateCompetitionCategory());

    return redirect()->route('competition-categories' , [$competitionCategory]);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're forgetting the id in form, this should fix your problem:

```
action="/competition-categories/{{$competitionCategory->id}}"
```

Comment: Thanks... Always where you don't look... I should have been able to do this myself, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The most common thing that this happens is your cache. When you add a new route or change something in your routes, always run after `php artisan optimize` to refresh you cache.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the named-routes for more informations and messages see =>

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes